# Establish connection with sql sql server using java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

Can you help me in establishing connection with sqlserver.

I am working on test automation with TestNG Framework.
For database validation , I need to establish connection with sql server.

I have one main class , which is having the below code:

```
private static String sqlServerClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
private static String sqlServerConnectionString = 
                    "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbname;DatabaseName=%s;domain=MS;useNTLMv2=true";

public static Connection openSqlServerConnection(String databaseName, String userName,
            String password) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, 
                                    IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, 
                                    IOException {
    Class.forName(sqlServerClassName).newInstance();
    sqlServerConnection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(String.format(sqlServerConnectionString, databaseName),
                                   userName, password);

}
```

the user name and password, I am getting from a property file.

But when I run the code , I am getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed.  
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Can anyone help with the issue .

Comment: The error is clear: fix your credentials.  Why aren't you using the Microsoft driver for SQL Server?

Comment: the credentials are correct , with the same credentials , i am able to connect to sql server directly

Comment: You might have to include the domain name before the username, like `YOURDOMAIN\username`

Comment: sqlServerConnection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(String.format(sqlServerConnectionString, databaseName),
                                   YOURDOMAIN\userName, password);    are you saying like this , because its throwing an error.. and in the connection string also i have mentioned : private static String sqlServerConnectionString = 
                    "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbname;DatabaseName=%s;domain=MS;useNTLMv2=true";